# Use record rows as columns BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have a table with rows like this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV7Gz.png), where each row of the table has records in an array form.

Using Bigquery,
Is there a way I can turn this into a table that has 'a', 'b', 'c' as its own columns, with 100, 46, 29 as the values in the rows?

I.e.
turn

```
Row | abc_keys | abc_intValues
------------------------------
1   | a        | 100
    | b        | 46
    | c        | 29
2   | a        | 101
    | b        | 47
    | c        | 30
```

into

```
Row | a   | b  | c
-------------------
1   | 100 | 46 | 29
2   | 101 | 47 | 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(row_hash) from (
  select keys, intValues, to_json_string(t) row_hash
  from your_table t, unnest(abc)
)
pivot (any_value(intValues) for keys in ('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]